# Is it possible to find length of sum of two binary numbers without calculating sum?

Tags: arithmetic, number-theory, binary

I'm doing an assignment where I need to multiply two 16 bit numbers and store result as an 16 bit integer array.

`a` is binary with length of `n`

`b` is binary with length of `m`

I have already found out that `a * b` would have length of `n + m` if `a` and `b` are repdigits consisting of `1` or `n + m - 1` if they're not.

Can I also find length of `a + b`?

Comment: It's either the maximum length of a and b or one more, but what simplification of rules are you looking for?

Comment: (There are natural numbers. And there are, say, integral numbers of both signs, the sum of which can be quite short.)

Comment: `110*110=100100`; I don't think `110` is a "repdigit".

Comment: @rici Thank you.

Comment: @Askeroni Nothing specific. Just looking for ways to simplify carry handling in cases where multiple array elements get affected by sum.